# How execute a Teradata Store Procedure in SAS program?

Tags: sas, teradata

I have a store procedure in Teradata and I trying execute with "PROC SQL" in SAS but I don't have results.

```
libname S_SQUEMA teradata server="100.00.00.100" user=##### pwd=#### schema=S_SQUEMA fastload=YES;

PROC SQL;
CALL S_SQUEMA.SP_TEST(year);
QUIT;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to connect your SAS session to Teradata?  Do that first. Then look at the EXECUTE statement of PROC SQL.  Then edit your question with any additional questions or details about what is not working.

Comment: Hello, yes of course, I have the first lines with the call of the libraries with the connection to Teradata.

Comment: There is no SAS statement named  `CALL S_SQUEMA.SP_TEST`. Show the full SAS code (with any private details masked) and any messages from your SAS log.

Comment: I add more details from the SAS file I use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run something in Teradata you need to connect to Teradata using a CONNECT statement and then push the Teradata code to the database using the EXECUTE statement.  So your code will look something like this:

```
proc sql ;
  connect to teradata ..... ;
  execute ( call S_SQUEMA.SP_TEST(year) ) by teradata;
quit;
```

If you already ran your `LIBNAME` statement to define your S_SQUEMA libref then you can just use that to make the connection.

```
proc sql ;
  connect using S_SQUEMA ;
  execute ( call S_SQUEMA.SP_TEST(year) ) by S_SQUEMA;
quit;
```